# Using template in angular directive works but templateUrl doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have the [following example](http://plnkr.co/edit/muYLOXclILeoaEMtbmVF?p=preview).

1. In the example I'm using kendo menu with angular directive for kendo. Each item in the menu is my custom directive. When I use template inside the directive is works fine but when I use templateUrl it doesn't work, any ideas?
2. The reason I am using a custom directive for the menu is because I couldn't find out how to register click of a specific item in the menu. There is an event in kendo menu (select) that I can use to register all menu item selections but then in the callback function I don't know which item was selected because there is no id on the DOM element and I also don't get the model data so there is no indication of what was clicked. How can I know that the "Open" menu was clicked for example?

Comment: your plunker link doesn't show the view even though u r using template.

Comment: That's strange... I do see it. Here is a similar example in js Bin but here the template url doesn't work at all... http://jsbin.com/uDiLAQIn/45/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The directive `kendo-menu` bootstraps the kendo menu from it's content. If you are using a `template` all is fine because the sub html structure is created before kendo bootstraps the menu. If you are using a `templateUrl` the template gets loaded and if the data arrive angular updates the dom in your directive. But at this time the `kendo-menu` directive is ready with bootstrapping the menu, so it will not be aware of any changes angular made on the dom. How to solve this: as you did - only use inline templates or put the templates to the templateCache before you used the template. But this requires a lot of changes to your code.

2) I am not quite sure where your problem is. But you may register a `ng-click` function like this:

```
<ul kendo-menu>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menuData.dataSource">
        <label>{{item.text}}</label>
        <ul>
           <li ng-click="menuSelected(subitem)" ng-repeat="subitem in item.items/>
              <label>{{subitem.text}}</label>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in your controller you have access to the selected item:

```
$scope.menuSelected = function(selected){
   console.log(selected);
}
```

here is the working <kbd>[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/muYLOXclILeoaEMtbmVF?p=preview)</kbd>

If you populate the menu from a dataSource you can specifiy a select function in your menuData:

```
$scope.menuData = {
    select: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.item.textContent);
     },
    dataSource: [ ... ] };
```

`e.item.textContent` is the value that you have provided in your `dataSource` as `text`.

Comment: #2 is in case I'm not rendering a content but using "k-options", in this case the menu renders the content itself so I can't add ng-click.

Comment: can you change your plunkr in this way? so i can check this?

Comment: I have one more question regarding my example: when using menu-item directive I regist to click with ng-click. The problem with this is that the click bubbles up, so if clicking inner menu item the click of the outer menu item being triggered as well. To solve this I add $event.stopPropagation(); but this also stops menu behavior such as closing the menu when item is clicked. I don't know how to prevent bubbling without stop the menu default behavior.

Comment: #2 see my edit. you can provide a select function to your menu config; bubbling - difficult. You can get access to the menu and close it by yourself:  var menu = $("#menu").data("kendoMenu");    menu.close("#Item1"); -> http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/menu, but this is not the angular way:(

Comment: What if I don't want to use the textContent but get some id or even the data model itself... I don't know how to get it. I can't use the text to indicate what was clicked.